# is it possible to search for documents with missing fields in lucene?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

i have data that looks like the following.

```
X1, X2, X3
1,  1,  0
0,  0,  1
```

if you notice, there are 3 columns: X1, X2, and X3. the values for each of these columns are only 1 or 0. each row in this data is desired to be indexed as a lucene Document, and each column per row, is desired to be indexed as a lucene Field.

in reality, the number of columns i have is over 100,000. also, this data is very sparse; meaning, the overwhelming majority of values are zeros. when i attempt to index each row as a Document, i get an OutOfMemoryError. of course, i can tinker with the JVM Xms and Xmx settings as well as the IndexWriterConfig to try an get around this memory problem. (who knows, but there may also be a limit to the number of fields per Document in lucene). my code looks something like the following.

```
IndexWriter writer = ...
BufferedReader reader = ....
String line = null;
while(null != (line = reader.readLine()) {
 String[] tokens = line.split(",");
 Document doc = new Document();
 for(int i=0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  doc.add(new IntField("x"+i, Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]), Field.Store.NO));
 }
 writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

however, what i really want to do, since the data set is sparse, is to index a column value as a Field only if its value is 1. i am thinking this will save space and be more memory efficient when constructing the Document and lucene index. so i want to modify my code's for loop to look like the following.

```
 for(int i=0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  int val = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
  if(0 != val)
   doc.add(new IntField("x"+i, val, Field.Store.NO));
 }
```

my question is this: if i do not index columns with values of zeros as fields per row, can i query for Documents not having a field?

for example, if i naively index all the fields regardless of a value of 0 or 1, i can perform a query as follows.

```
IndexReader reader = ...
IndexSearcher searcher = ...
Query q1 = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("x1", 1, 1, true, true);
Query q2 = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("x2", 0, 0, true, true);
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(q1, Occur.MUST);
query.add(q2, Occur.MUST);
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, null, 1);
```

this will give me all documents where x1=1 and x2=0.

if i take the sparse indexing approach (where i don't index fields with a value of zero), is it possible to query for documents where x1=1 and x2=0. if so, could someone please give me an example?

i have read that you can do this type of query with elasticsearch (and solr), but i cannot use such technologies in my environment. also, i did get some search results on the internet investigating this problem, but the posts are from dealing with earlier versions of lucene (e.g. one post was in 2005).

please note that i am working with jdk 1.7 32-bit and lucene v4.4.

any help is appreciated.

i just thought of something and i will try it out. may be i can index each row in one field as follows.

```
x1=0 x2=1 x3=0
x1=0 x2=0 x3=1
```

and then i can perform a boolean query for "x1=0" and "x2=1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can perform such a query, by getting all documents, and eliminating those with a value (using `Occur.MUST_NOT`), something like:

```
Query qx2 = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("x2", 1, 1, true, true);
Query matchAll = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
Query qnotx2 = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(matchAll, Occur.MUST);
query.add(qx2, Occur.MUST_NOT);
Query qx1 = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("x1", 1, 1, true, true);
Query query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(qx1, Occur.MUST);
query.add(qnotx2, Occur.MUST);
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, null, 1);
```

However, this is unlikely to save much space in memory, in any way I can imagine.  As far as storage, the fields are not stored, and common values in the index should take up trivial amounts of space.  Performance at query time will be much worse with this approach, and you would be much better served indexing the the zeroes.

Comment: do you know if there is an upper limit to the number of Fields per Document in lucene v4.4?

Comment: would indexing everything in one field work? e.g. index the text, "x1=0 x2=0 x3=1"? is it possible to then query for any Document where the Field has "x1=0 and x2=0"?

Comment: I don't believe there is a built in limit on the number of fields in a document.  Hardware limitations should be the only restriction, as far as I know.

Comment: And yes, you could certainly index everything in one field.  That would probably be a good implementation to try, but you'll need to choose your Analyzer carefully.  [WhitespaceAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html) would probably be a strong choice.